# How to set sender name by postal?

Tags: clojure

The postal
https://github.com/drewr/postal

I want to send mail with clojure, but I don't know how to set sender name.

This my code.

```
 (defn smtp []
  {:host (env :mail-host)
   :user (env :mail-user)
   :pass (env :mail-pass)
   :ssl :yes!!!11})

(defn mail [request]
  {:from "demo@gmail.com"
   :to "demo2@gmail.com"
   :subject "subject"
   :body "body"})

(defn send [request]
  (p/send-message (smtp) (mail request)))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the address from `demo@gmail.com` to `Your Name <demo@gmail.com>`

```
(defn mail [request]
  {:from "Tornado <demo@gmail.com>"
   :to "Hurricane <demo2@gmail.com>"
   :subject "subject"
   :body "body"})
```

Comment: Actually I have modified it. your mean is `:from (env :mail-user)`? I cant send mail successfully just can't set sender name such “Tornado”.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show exactly what you need to change.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's valid.